# What should the return type be for a method that returns &str or new string with the lifetime of the parent?

Tags: rust

I want to create an `id` method which either returns an id, which is a struct attribute, or a new string.

What should be my return type? `&str` for returning a struct attribute `self.title`, but then what is the return type of a new string with lifetime of the calling scope?

```
fn id(&self) -> &str {
    match self.type {
        PageType::Type1 => format!("{}-{}", self.title, self.page_num),
        PageType::Type2 => &self.title,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

There are three ways you can implement this, with different trade-offs.

## Return an owned string

You return `String` and use `self.title.clone()`.

- Pros: Simple.
- Cons: Allocates a new string on every call, even in the simple case.

Use when you have no reason to think that this might become a performance issue, and you want the simplicity of simply returning `String`.

## Store the id in the struct

Build it in the constructor function. (Building it on-demand is also possible, but incurs complicated lifetime issues.) Return a `&str`. There is hardly ever a good reason to use `&String`.

- Pros: Very cheap call.
- Cons: Need to store the id. Need to keep it up-to-date when the `title` or `page_num` fields change.

Use if accessed *very* frequently.

## Return a [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html)

This type is capable of representing either a borrowed or an owned thing, and via deref coercion acts like the borrowed thing in usage.

```
fn id(&self) -> Cow<str> {
    match self.ty {
        PageType::Type1 => Cow::Owned(format!("{}-{}", self.title, self.page_num)),
        PageType::Type2 => Cow::Borrowed(&self.title),
    }
}
```

- Pros: Efficient in the simple case. Doesn't increase struct size. Doesn't need complicated code to maintain the id.
- Cons: The usage is slightly more complicated, depending on what the user does with the result. Still allocates a new string in the complex case.

This makes a good default to use, unless you really want to keep the API as simple as possible.

Comment: *"you could return a Cow, but that complicates usage of the method"* : Isn't that the perfect use case for a `Cow` ? Your comment makes it look like it's not the best solution here and I fear it might be badly interpreted.

Comment: The perfect use case for `Cow` is when the efficiency gain is worth the usability loss. Since I don't know what the use case is, I can't say what the best way is. But I could formulate the post in a more neutral manner.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by usability loss, Cow has been design to be a user friendly tool. Also in my opinion the most important is that cow feature have a overheat, people often forget that, small I agree, but always keep in mind that some feature doesn't come for free. (but that a free abstraction ofc)

Comment: I've rewritten the post to be more balanced. The usability loss comes from having a wrapper. Yes, deref coercion means that many usages are the same, but under some circumstances, the user actually has to understand what having a cow means.